# Finding surjective but non-injection mapping from integers to the positive integers

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Find an example of a function of a set of all integers to the set of positive integers that is surjective, but not injective.

I also need to prove it. I have tried but had no success. Even if I do find one, how would I prove it?

**Background:** OK, so I have run into this weird question about recurrence relations that I cannot complete by myself (first year comp. sci. student and first discrete math class, studying by myself due to quarantine). I study in a non-english university, so I am sorry if I haven't properly translated it. Now I am bad at this type of math and relations/funtions are the worst for me. I have spent some time on this question, but I cannot see the answer, so please try to be a bit precise in your answers. I am sure that I will understand it if someone can provide a good explanation. Thanks, your help will be very appreciated!!! :D

Comment: Hint:  try to make such a function using the absolute value.

Comment: @lulu I'm asking because I am new to this. Is it better style to give hints instead of providing complete answers?

Comment: @Mikal If you can take a hint and construct your own answer, there’s no point of writing a complete solution.

Comment: @Mikal It depends.  For homework style problems, like this one, I think a hint is better.  Especially when, as here, the user has not indicated any real sort of effort.  In other contexts, where the solution looks very elusive a full solution is clearly better.

Comment: This sounds like good advice. I guess I've been a bit rephungry.

Answer (score 0):

Another on is to let $f(n) = \lvert n \rvert + 1$. Then for all $z \geq 1$ in the positive integers we know that 
$$f(z-1) = f(-z+1) = z$$
Thus for any element $z$ in the codomain (positive integers) there is at least one element in the domain (all integers) that map to $z$. By definition the mapping is surjective.

More specifically, $z=1$ is mapped to only by $0$ but all remaining positive integers can be mapped to by both $-z+1$ and $z-1$.

However notice that $f(z-1) = f(-z+1)$ which means the mapping cannot be injective.